# Unable to connect the sql database using azure

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-rm-template

I have a SQL Server in Azure which is created using a simple ARM template. When I connect to the SQL Server using my sqladmin credentials I am **able** to connect to it fine. I am using SQL Server Management Studio for this.

[image]

However, When I use any of the following highlighted options, I am seeing an error message.
[image]

The Error I am seeing is as shown below, its a pop-up window but I am pasting the text in it for easy reference.

```
TITLE: Connect to Server
------------------------------
Cannot connect to abcd-core-sql.database.windows.net.
------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
```

> ```
> **Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)**
> ```

```
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=18456&LinkId=20476
```

I would appreciate if anyone can comment on if I am missing anything in creating a SQL Server using the ARM template.In other words is there anything else that needs to be included in the config to get the azure ad authentication working for a sql db in azure.

```
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers",
        "name": "[variables('sql_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-05-01-preview",
        "location": "eastus2",
        "properties": {
            "administratorLogin": "[parameters('admin')]",
            "administratorLoginPassword": "[parameters('passwd')]",
            "version": "[variables('sqlversion')]"
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 2):

You must configure an Azure Active Directory Admin for the instance before you can connect with AAD credentials or create any AAD Database Users.  See [Configure and manage Azure AD authentication with Azure SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)

Once you've set the AAD Administrator, connect as the AAD Admin or a member of the AAD Security Group set as the AAD Admin and [Create contained users mapped to Azure AD identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-users-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities), eg

```
CREATE USER [bob@contoso.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

or

```
CREATE USER [ICU Nurses] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
```

Comment: thanks. i added myself as admin from portal and was able to login now. but how does the configuration/management of other users work. if i want to let users login with their own AD credentials. is that possible

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, to fix, you need to click on the  button then on the  tab and on the field  you have to replace  with the database name you want/have access.

The issue happens because the default database for the user is the master database but the user doesn't have access to the master database.

Another option is to give the user access to the master database, but usually you don't want this.

Answer (score 0):

For the ARM template here is what can be added inside the sql Server Resource:

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "ActiveDirectory",
      "type": "administrators",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "apiVersion": "2019-06-01-preview",
      "properties": {
        "administratorType": "ActiveDirectory",
        "login": "[parameters('sqlADadmin')]",
        "sid": "[parameters('sqlADadminObjectID')]",
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Sql/servers', variables('sqlServerName'))]"
      ]
    }
```

Here is the [API documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.sql/2019-06-01-preview/servers/administrators)

Not you need **both** the Azure AD objectId and the login name of the account/group you are making sql admins.

This can be obtain via [Get-AzureADUser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/get-azureaduser?view=azureadps-2.0) in Powershell or in the [Portal](http://blog.schertz.name/2018/06/locating-ids-in-azure-ad/)