# Connecting to SQL Server using Powershell with Azure AD MFA

Tags: sql-server, powershell, authentication, azure-active-directory

I am trying to connect to my Azure SQL instance using an Access Token from Azure AD. I was following this tutorial over here: https://medium.com/microsoftazure/deploying-a-dacpac-to-azure-with-azure-pipelines-and-managed-identity-89703d405e00

But something is not working right in the approach.

The first thing was to make sure my user was setup in the database via:

```sql
CREATE USER [myemail@email.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
```

Which is the same process from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62161471/1963929

And then I tested both SQL Server Management Studio and Azure Data Studio, both worked perfectly.

[image]

But when I try exactly the same thing in Powershell it does not work, all I get is the dread `Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.`

Here’s what I tried

```sql
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection

$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=tcp:azure-sql.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=default;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30"

$conn.AccessToken = $(az account get-access-token --resource=https://database.windows.net/ --query accessToken)

$conn.Open()
```

The error that I receive when connecting to my db is the following

> MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user ''."

Then I thought “maybe I’m using the wrong settings” so I tried the using a client id that my app is using to connect to the same db. And this time I tested multiple scopes: none, `.default`, and `user_impersonation`.

```sql
$clientid = "azure-data-studio-client-id"
$request = Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/devicecode" -Body @{client_id=$clientid; scope="https://database.windows.net/user_impersonation"} -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$request.message


$tokens = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Body @{client_id=$clientid; grant_type="urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:device_code"; code = $request.device_code} -ContentType "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
$accesstoken = $tokens.access_token
```

So I thought maybe Azure Data Studio has superpowers, and used another account in there without doing `CREATE USER` and I got  the right error

[image]

And this error proves me that `CREATE USER` is necessary, but it does not explain why I can't do this via Powershell.

I also tried Node and Tedious like the following:

```js
      const dbConfig = {
        authentication: {
          type: "azure-active-directory-access-token",
          options: {
            token: token
          }
        },
        server: getDatabasePerEnvironment(environment),
        database: databaseName,
        options: {
          trustServerCertificate: false,
          encrypt: true,
          port: 1433
        }
      };
      const connection = new tedious.Connection(dbConfig);
```

Same error:

> "ConnectionError: Login failed for user ''.

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue, and my problem is more minuscule than I thought.

I found my answer in this answer: [Azure SQL Grant Access for AD User using PowerShell and ServicePrincipal](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62677458/1963929)

What's happening is this line:

`$conn.AccessToken = $(az account get-access-token --resource=https://database.windows.net/ --query accessToken)`

returns an Access Token wrapped in Double Quotes

`$conn.AccessToken = $(az account get-access-token  --subscription $subscription --resource https://database.windows.net  --query accessToken -o tsv)`

That `-o tsv` at the end will trim the double quotes from the output.

On TediousJS the problem was that I was doing

```
const tokenPayload = JSON.parse(execSync("az account get-access-token").toString());
```

What I needed to be doing is:

```
const tokenPayload = execSync(
    "az account get-access-token  --subscription YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION --resource https://database.windows.net  --query accessToken -o tsv"
  ).toString();
```

So the steps you need to do to use the Azure CLI token with SQL Server are the following:

1. Configure an Active Directory Admin on Azure SQL
2. Execute something like the following to add your user

```
CREATE USER [youremail@mail.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [youremail@mail.com];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [youremail@mail.com];
ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [youremail@mail.com];
```

3. Confirm you can connect with Azure AD with SSMS or Azure Data Studio
4. Try the following:

```
$conn = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SQLConnection 
$conn.ConnectionString = "Server=yourserver.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=Subledger;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30"

$conn.AccessToken = $(az account get-access-token --subscription YOUR-SUBSCRIPTION --resource https://database.windows.net --query accessToken -o tsv)

$conn.Open()
```

Comment: I tried to follow along with your code, but I am still getting: "Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'." when trying to open the connection. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: @Asher, the base hello world you can do is create user first and try to connect with a tool (like sql server management studio or azure data studio), is that part working for you?

Comment: yes, I am able to connect with SSMS using 'Azure Active Directory with MFA' and my email address.

Comment: A few minutes later I was able to resolve it. In my connection string I changed the initial catalog to master instead of default and the error disappeared.

Comment: @Asher glad to hear that! it is probable that default is going to a database that needs CREATE USER too

Comment: It didn't quite make sense to me because the user I'm working with is part of the Active Directory Administrators, which should have permission to all databases by default.